# Laravel 4 services.json failed to open stream

Tags: php, laravel, centos

When I access my Centos production server, I got this debug message:

`ErrorException
file_put_contents(/var/www/projectplanner/releases/20140610043651/app/storage/meta/services.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

I have already checked many similar topics on the matter but no good (like chmod 777, clear php artisan cache...)
Here is the `ls -l` of my production server
[image: File permission]

Comment: uhmm are you sure you have write permissions on the `services.json` itself? This `ls -l` doesn't show much.

Comment: so how can I check that? I'm new to Centos

Comment: `cd DIRNAME` will change current directory, so you could go into each one and check permissions... OR simply use `chmod -R 777 app` as Flextra already said, and don`t worry about checking.

Comment: nah, this will not do. I have chmod even from `/var/` to deeper folders. I stated in the question that `chmod` didn't help

Comment: I've had the same problem once or twice, where chmod -R 777 app/storage wouldn't work, but removing the file meta/services.json manually did. It's annoying, but it's worked for me, and the file is a temporary file so it's safe to remove it. Worth a shot at least. :)

Comment: have you tried it from the directory in your picture? Not before, you must be in that directory if you use relative position...

Comment: thank you @Dexa, I have tried all the folders. I just snap a general screenshot

Comment: There is no magic. what if that file recreated with old permissions ? what if you have another user for apache and other system trying to write it ? you need to figure that out. you can open /etc/init.d/tomcat-service-name in text editor and look there for the user which tomcat starts up from. and what do you mean by 'access production server on centos' ? how do you do that ?